# How to get rid of extra leading spaces in the rendering of the result of a formula in Microsoft Word?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-word, text-formatting, rendering

This has annoyed me for some time. Consider any formula that outputs a number, and give it a formatting string. I.e.: `{ =exchange_rate \# "#,##0.00000" }`. Then this will render as:

[image]

I can now remove the surplus spaces by hand, but each time I hit F9, it will add the spaces again. If i get rid of the thousand-separator part in the formatting string, i.e. `{ =exchange_rate \# "0.00000" }`, it'll render just fine. But `#` is supposed to render as "digit if there is one, or nothing otherwise".

Is it possible to have it both ways? Use the formatting string with the thousand-separator, but have the result properly left-trimmed so that the result looks like this?

[image]

This is in Word 2016, it is possible if this is not happening in newer versions, in which case I'll just upgrade.

Comment: Remark: The definition of the `#` is "A number if present; otherwise, a **blank space**". I don't know of a solution to this problem.

Comment: @harrymc, tx, that'd explain the behavior, but do you have a reference for that? I thought the formatting string followed the same logic as [`String.Format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format?view=net-5.0#legacy-code-example) in .NET, I couldn't readily find the formatting string rules w.r.t. MS Word.

Comment: See [Working with Fields and Forms in Word 2016](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2455715&seqNum=5).